# SQL acceptable value range when inserting data into table

Tags: sql

When inserting values in to table is there any method to avoid getting invalid data into columns?

ex Table - Item

```
Itno - pk
Itdesc
salesprice - Acceptable values should > 150 and < 10500
```

ty

Comment: create a constraint on this field in table. which db you are using.

Comment: Different DB have constraint systems, but usually, long before you even consider writing into the DB, you should have sanitized the inputs, informed the user of errors, made computations to produce values to write or change the program state, and so on.

So if you're only asking your DB to do it, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: What database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, not a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 1):

Following syntax is applicable to MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
Itno int NOT NULL,
Itdesc varchar(255) NOT NULL,
salesprice  int,
CONSTRAINT chk_salesprice  CHECK (salesprice >150 AND salesprice < 10500)
)
```

You can also use user defined functions with Check Constraint to validate the dynamic value.

[UDF with Check Constraint](http://connectsql.blogspot.in/2011/01/sql-server-function-based-check.html)

[Refer to see more examples](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Romil's answer, most RDBMS's support *triggers* which can validate data before or after a commit.

Generally a `CHECK` constraint is preferred, but sometimes (especially in the cases where the data must be evaluated against a variable standard) a trigger is the only way to do it.